# Highcharts touchscreens detection

Tags: highcharts, touchscreen

Is it possible to detect touchscreens directly with Highcharts ? I don't find what i want in the documentation.

I can use tools like `Modernizr.touchevents` but i don't want to import useless scripts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Highcharts has property Highcharts.hasTouch which is used internally for checking for touch events - http://jsfiddle.net/yco2La86/.

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot morganfree ! The solution:

> Highcharts has property `Highcharts.hasTouch` which is used internally for checking for touch events - [jsfiddle.net/yco2La86](http://jsfiddle.net/yco2La86)